# Different JNDI provider url for one case

Tags: java, jndi, lookup

I use remote EJB call to run my program.

Third party jar(who performs that call) needs different "java.naming.provider.url" than system one.

Any way to specify different provider url only for some scope/class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the initial context you can specify such things. Example:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
...
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
      "com.somecompany.naming.TheirInitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,
      "corbaname:iiop:myhost.mycompany.com:9810/NameServiceServerRoot");
Context initialContext = new InitialContext(env);
```

Comment: I meant: is it possible to specify provider to _third party_ code if thirdparty code does not provide possibility to use different context(e.g. no methods/constructors). I knew it is stupid but I was in despair. But I found method that accepts my context. I'll mark your answer as correct.